# What is the purpose of set { return; }?

Tags: c#, accessor

I've seen the following code in various places:

```
 namespace My.name.space
    {
        class myClass
        {       
            public CustomObject Name
            {
                get { return new CustomObject (this.Dog); }
                set { return; }
            }

        }
    }
```

What is the purpose of `set { return; }`?

I don't understand what purpose set return would serve.

I would think you could just remove the set accessor completely.

Comment: A no-op `set` allows attempts at setting the property to compile and then fail silently. If you've got a grudge against your employer and you just got laid off, maybe it makes sense. There might imaginably be some point if the property were virtual, but I still don't like it. The `return` serves no purpose but typing practice.

Comment: The `return;`can be omitted. The set-method is void anyway.

Comment: As a closely related aside, I think this code should be a method and not a property according to these [MSDN Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx): "Do use a method (if) ... The operation returns a different result each time it is called, even if the parameters do not change". I feel like the "empty" setter was the programmer saying, "Hey it doesn't even make sense to 'set' anything because the 'get' returns a new object every single time anyway", but that is just a code smell that it shouldn't be a property in the first place.

Comment: @Quantic Has a good point -- although it may also be that the class should be keeping a private `CustomObject` field that's updated when/if the value of `Dog` changes; in that case `Name` would be a property that returns that field.  Of course, if you found this in a dusty corner of an old code base and it's not actively causing any problems, it's likely not a high priority for a round of Regression Bug Roulette.

Comment: If you down-vote a question, please leave a reason.

Comment: @CSharpie -- putting `return;` there shows it was deliberate to future devs, whereas omitting it looks like a mistake.  Of course, a comment always helps.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

None.  It's somebody who doesn't quite know that a read-only property can be expressed much more simply by not including the `set`

```
public Derp MuhDerp { get { return _derp; } }
```

Interesting point brought up by CSharpie in a comment...

If you *have* to have a `set` because it is defined in an interface, you can add the `set` but omit the return:

```
public Derp MuhDerp { get { return _derp; } set { } }
```

Of course, if the interface defines a setter, you should probably make sure it works as expected :)

Comment: Unless its defined by an interface.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically to give the illusion that there is a setter, well there is, but does nothing. But it was probably done to keep some interface happy or a parent class:

```
public CustomObject Name
{
   get { return new CustomObject( this.Dog ); }
   set { return; } // does absolutely nothing
}
```

Here is a class:

```
public abstract class A {
   public abstract void DoWork();
   public abstract string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Here is giving the illusion that it is implementing the abstract interface, but it really is not implementing everything:

```
public class B : A {
   public override string SomeProperty
   {
      get
      {
         return "whatever";
      }

      set
      {
         return; // keep interface happy
      }
   }

   public override void DoWork() {
      // I am not doing nothing but compiler is happy
   }
}
```

That code also breaks [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/30/simplifying-the-liskov-substitution-principle-of-solid-in-c.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

That simply means "don't do anything, I don't want to make an assignment".  It's like a no-op in the setter.  It's also equivalent to an empty setter, i.e. `set { }`.  It's a matter of preference, really; some people prefer not to have empty code bodies, I guess.

Of course, you wouldn't typically do it that way (as Will points out).  You would just use a read-only property, but there is a key difference: when using a read-only property, an attempt to set it will fail *at compile time*; if you're using the one you asked about, then it won't fail at all, it will simply "do nothing" at runtime.

Which one you use largely depends on what you want your application to do.  I'll point out that using this approach (rather than a read-only property) can lead to brittle code, as the programmer may not be aware that their deliberate attempt to assign a value is being ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Properties in C# are just syntax candy for a special case of methods.

A "regular" property like

```
public int Foo {get;set;}
```

is actually (sommething similiar)

```
int _foo;
public int get_Foo() { return _foo;}
public void set_Foo(int value) { _foo = value;}
```

However you are allowed to speficy yourself, what happens in the setter and getter

```
public int Foo { get { return 47; } set { Console.WriteLine(value); } }
```

So taking your example the compiler will turn it into

```
public CustomObject get_Name() { return new CustomObject (this.Dog); }
public void set_Name(CustomObject value) { return; }
```

Which does nothing in the set-Method at all. So why would someone do this?
There are a few reasons that make sense:

- They want to later introduce functionality to that setter, so it serves as a placeholder for now
- The setter is required, because the Property comes from an interface, yet it makes no sense to set the value in that concrete implementation
- Some API or stuff based on reflection requires a set-method even if it is not used.

Answer (score 0):

this is the same as a read only property, but the property can be setted (obviously with no sense).

Answer (score 0):

There are some great answers here (and I know this is an old question), but I wanted to provide some additional context for what this is, when it might be useful, and how I've used it in production code.

First, the answer: This is normally not useful. Just define a readonly property. As others have said, you're completely right that you could remove the set and have *almost* the same effect -- except that the property could no longer be assigned to.

Now, here's where this can be useful. For a lot of the smaller microservices I write, I use Azure Tables for storage. This is a key-value database, where your key comes in two parts: a PartitionKey and a RowKey. They're pretty self-explanatory.

Generally I'll end up with a couple of small tables (such as  ones holding basic application-managed settings) that don't make sense to use a PartitionKey with -- i.e. they only have one identifying piece of information, such as an id, along with a value.

The `Azure.Data.Tables` library is really nice, and provides an interface to implement for your DTOs. Implementing this interface would normally look like the following:

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;

namespace SmartsheetIntegration.Qar.DataStores.Models;

public class MyDto : ITableEntity 
{
    public MyDto() {}

    public MyDto(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Now, what about these simple app settings? I want to make sure that they *never* end up with a PartitionKey, because I need to know for sure that if I want to retrieve all of them, I can query for `'PartitionKey = ""'` and get everything back.

The simple solution to this is:

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Data.Tables;

namespace SmartsheetIntegration.Qar.DataStores.Models;

public class MyDto : ITableEntity 
{
    public MyDto() {}

    public MyDto(string partitionKey, string rowKey)
    {
        PartitionKey = partitionKey;
        RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public string PartitionKey
    {
        get => "";
        set { } // the same as set { return; }
    }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? Timestamp { get; set; }
    public ETag ETag { get; set; }
}
```

Now Azure Tables can do whatever it wants in its library, but I can guarantee that the PartitionKey saved to the database will always be an empty string.

So yes, the number of situations where this is useful isn't huge -- but there are interface implementations where it makes sense.